# Defective component probability

Tags: probability

A lot of components contain 5% defectives. Each component is subjected to a test that correctly identifies a defective, but given a component is good, there is a 2% chance that these components are also indicated defective. Given a randomly chosen component is declared defective by the tester, compute the probability that it is actually defective.

Comment: Hmmm... I wonder how the "$5$% defectives" piece of information could have any effect on the answer...

Comment: I think that part is only stating a fact of components

Comment: So isn't the answer simply $98$%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Bayes' formula:
$$
P(A|B)=\frac{P(A)P(B|A)}{P(B)}
$$
Define $A$ as defective, $B$ as shown defective by test. So we have
$$
P(A|B) = \frac{0.05*1}{0.95*0.02+0.05}
$$